# Dynamic height using 2 columns in a wrapper in css

Tags: html, css, height, multiple-columns

I have the following html layout and depending on what page i'm on either the inner-left div or the inner-right div may have more content. How can I structure the css code so that the wrap div's height is equal to the larger of either inner divs? My current code only expands the outer div based on the left column but if the right column has more content it doesn't work properly. I was using min-height on the left column but that doesn't work very well. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Thanks

HTML:
`

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="inner-left">
        content left
    </div>

    <div id="inner-right">
         content right
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap{
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
position: relative;
}

#inner-left{
    overflow: auto;
}

#inner-right{
    position:absolute;margin-left:640px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `overflow:hidden` to the parent should make it try to wrap your content. Try this:

```
#wrap{
   overflow: hidden;
}

#inner-left{
    float:left;
}

#inner-right{
    float:right;
}
```